# Should I bother to flip basement ceiling insulation that's on backwards?

Tags: insulation, basement, ceiling

the rolled faced insulation on the ceiling of my unfinshed  unheated basement is on backwards(vapor barrier facing down instead of up towards the 1st floor),1st floor is uncovered hardwood. Insulation must be at least 25 years old and my basement gets very humid may-aug.( I run a dehumidifier) Is there any good reason for me to flip it over or even remove it altogether? I count twelve rows that are each 16 inches wide by 36 feet long.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is doublefaced (paper on both sides)?

Comment: No, only on one side and it's facing the wrong way. When I discovered it on wrong, my gut told me to fix it. I need advice on whether doing this is worth the effort. It is an unrenovated 100 yr old house.I undoubtedly will find    "something" else once ceiling is exposed(mice scat, defunct wiring etc, cracks to be filled) This does not concern me. Is this an important thing to do as far as insulating an unheated and unfinished basement? I will do it if advised, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The vapor barrier may have been done correctly; it depends on several factors like temperature, whether the basement is a living area, or if is a laundry area or has other sources of moisture build up. You need to ask your local inspector.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced that it's backward, either. Seems like you'd want the insulation on the dry side in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree, the paper usually goes toward the conditioned side, in this case I would that is the subfloor side since the basement is so humid

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It isn't clear what you're trying to say: agree with what?

Comment: Agree that I do not think it is backward as installed. The paper usually goes to the conditioned side, and if the basement is humid, the conditioned side would be toward the upper floor, so it sounds like it is correct as installed.

Comment: That's clearer, but the information is best put into the question itself so that someone reading it (without the comments) will understand. Otherwise it won't help people, and you are unlikely to get any up-votes.